I want to upload file via file uploader in admin panel ui component and it does not work on magento 2.4.7 but it works in magento 2.4.6
The resource from “http://site.local/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/file-uploader.js”
was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)
